# How to deploy reagent-frontend to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, clojurescript, reagent

I created a ClojureScript Reagent app from template reagent-frontend. How I can deploy production app to Heroku? After building for production (`lein package` / `lein cljsbuild once release`) leiningen generate `app.js` in folder `public`. As result public folder contain css/, js/, index.html.

On my attempt push folder `public` Heroku give next error:

```
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.

            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.

            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku can serve PHP so one way to go about it is by adding an `index.php` file to public with the following content `<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>` This will serve your own index.html. Then push that to Heroku.

Source: https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku